# Robolectric String.format() invalid behavior while formatting numbers

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, robolectric

In application there is a simple code:

```
String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", count)
```

And everything is fine but when user will select on phone Arabic language the numbers will be displayed in Arabic literal format ( obvious ).

**So where is the problem?**

I want replace Locale.getDefault() with Locale.US to get "normal" numbers but also want to write test for that.

And there is a problem. 
Robolectric in tests showing number for ex. "3" instead of "٢".

My Test Code:

```
public class SideMenuMainContentViewTest {

    private static final String ARABIC_LANGUAGE_LOCALE_CODE = "ar-rEG";

    private SideMenuMainContentView sideMenuMainContentView;
    private AttributeSet attributeSet;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        attributeSet = Robolectric.buildAttributeSet().build();

        sideMenuMainContentView = new SideMenuMainContentView(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), attributeSet);

    }

    @Test
    public void test_getBookedRidesCountText() {

        assertEquals("3", sideMenuMainContentView.getBookedRidesCountText(3));
    }

    @Test
    @Config(qualifiers = ARABIC_LANGUAGE_LOCALE_CODE)
    public void test_getBookedRidesCountText_notSupportedLanguage() {

        assertEquals("3", sideMenuMainContentView.getBookedRidesCountText(3));
    }
}
```

Any idea how to change this behaviour and get literal numbers in tests like when application is run?

Answer (score 1):

To make Eastern Arabic numerals like ٢ appear in unit tests, you can set the locale to `Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-u-nu-arab")` - using the factory method `forLanguageTag` and the BCP 47 language tag string "ar-u-nu-arab" which explicitly specifies an Arab numbering system. `new Locale("ar-u-nu-arab")` doesn't work as the constructor does not parse the numbering system.

See this link for more info on numbering systems in Java 8 locales: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html#num-systems